# Google Analytics - referal address - utmr field

Tags: hyperlink, google-analytics

I would like to craete a link to other page but without letting know Google Analytic (GA) that user is comming from my site. So field "utmr" need to by empty (0 | - ) and it must looks like user will enter www address in browser. Is there a any way that GA will not be able to read source website’s address?

```
 <a href="http://domain.com/a.html" > Destination A </a>
<a href="http://domain.com/Arel.html" rel="nofollow" rev="nofollow" target="_blank"> Destination A with rel </a>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:location.href='http://domain.com/Javascript.html'" > Destination javascript </a>
```

I have tried javascript, a html tags but with no success :/ Any help will be appreciated.

--
Jacek

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answers here [PHP - Referer Redirect Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857427/php-referer-redirect-script).

Basically, you cannot do this without having a site, such as [DontKnow.me](http://dontknow.me) or [LinkAnon](http://linkanon.com) to do a redirect. You can create your own script to do it but yea, it will still show coming from your site.

I would really take a look at that PHP Post though, it has great information regarding this and why you cannot do it.

**EDIT**

However, if you have control of the page you are redirecting to, you can probably find some method to override that setting if the referer is coming from your site. But that is assuming you have control over the site you are redirecting to.

Comment: Yes, if you have control over the target URL (the page the user is going to), you can use GA's \_setReferrerOverride() method to push what is reported as the referring URL. http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiCampaignTracking.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setReferrerOverride