# Third party image acces issue 403 error

Tags: http-status-code-403, hotlinking

I am facing one issue. I am accessing third party image into our site but it gives me 403 error. 
But I am able to access it if I am hitting that image url directly on browser.

Please provide what the reason behind it

Answer (score 1):

This image is not available for [hotlinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotlink). Service does checking of [referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer) and doesn't allow to embed image inside another sites. You can try to use proxying for that reason with short server-side script.

Please, refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857427/php-referer-redirect-script), if you're using PHP.

Comment: Thanks, But if I am accessing that image url using my local host it's opening it.

Comment: Through opening in browser? In that situation `referer` stays empty, and service accepts your request with ease. So, with script you can emulate this behaviour and be happy.

Comment: No I am not accessing it Directly on browser. I have made a test page in local Server and add that image path in the <img> image source. In that case it's opening perfectly. Referrer will empty in that case as well or what ?

Comment: Maybe service permits hotlinking from localhost - if you provide an example image URL i can start try to figure out this. Please, try the script that i mentioned in the answer.