# Unable to display pokemon image from pokeapi.co

Tags: reactjs, pokeapi

I am having an issue where I can't seem to be able to display the pokemon images on my react front end, this is the api: https://pokeapi.co/

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Card extends Component {
    state = {
        name: "",
        imageUrl: "",
        pokemonIndex: "",
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const {name, url} = this.props;
        const pokemonIndex = url.split('/')[url.split('/').length - 2];
        const imageUrl = `http://pokeapi.co/media/sprites/pokemon/${pokemonIndex}.png`
        this.setState({name, imageUrl, pokemonIndex})
    }
    render() {
        
       
        
        return (
            <div className="card" >
                <img src= {this.state.imageUrl}/>
                <h3> {this.state.name} </h3>
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Card;
```

I have also attached a screenshot of the front end.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Third party image acces issue 403 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503374/third-party-image-acces-issue-403-error)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the documentation and JSON file from API, I think I found your problem. You are using the wrong img link. The correct format is: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemonIndex}.png`

For exemple:

```html
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/132.png" />
```

Comment: where did you find this link? I couldn't find it anywhere on the documentation.

Comment: @RMP1992 I opened the json file and searched for png, then I tested the links to find the correct one

Answer (score 2):

@erick-silva answer is not complete and prone to error.

The correct way to fetch an image for a specific pokemon is:

1. Fetch from PokeAPI the info for that pokemon, say `bulbasaur`. -> `GET https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/bulbasaur`
2. Parse the returned JSON for the property `.sprites`, select the version we'd like to use and the variety for the sprite, say *Pokemon Crystal front*: `.sprites.versions["generation-ii"].crystal.front_default`
3. Use the provided link and load the image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/versions/generation-ii/crystal/1.png

Using this method will ensure that you will always fetch the correct image in case the `id`s change or the name of the image isn't the `id` of the pokemon.

Answer (score 2):

Currently `pokemon` images are not loaded as there are deleted from it's github repo.

You can find the real location of the images inside `sprites` folder in [PokeAPI](https://github.com/PokeAPI/sprites) GitHub.

To get the image, there is a workaround,

https://unpkg.com/pokeapi-sprites@2.0.2/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/1.svg

here `1.svg` should be replaced by the `pokemon's id`

You can find more info [here](https://unpkg.com/css-chain-test@1.0.8/src/PokeApi-Explorer.html)

Answer (score 0):

For pokeapi the correct URI format is as follows.

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/imageName.png
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It doesn't work that way

Answer (score 0):

As another option. If you need pictures not by id, but by name, then this link is available.

```
const name = 'bulbasaur'; 
`https://img.pokemondb.net/artwork/${name}.jpg`;
```

https://img.pokemondb.net/artwork/bulbasaur.jpg