# Change url referrer to look like comming from facebook using a redirect url

Tags: php, youtube, redirect, referrer

I made a pdf ebook where I embeded a link to a youtube video I uploaded.

on youtube stats, it shows that my traffic source is unknown.

I know this is hurting the seo of my video. This is why I am trying to enhance my youtube seo by making the visitors who come from my pdf looks like comming from facebook.

I know this is called faking the referral but I don't know if this can be done through this way:

1 _ user click on the link embeded in the PDF.

2 _ the user get redirected to "myscript.com".

3 _ "myscript.com" will redirect the user to youtube.

4 _ youtube stats show traffic comming from facebook.

please, if you know anything about this, help me.

Comment: [No, not possible.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12154042/1188035) Not to mention trying to scam Google will be damn near impossible or get caught very quickly.

Comment: I am not trying to scam Google. I just want to enhance my seo.

Comment: I dunno why someone has downed this question. bear in mind, what matter for GOOGLE is to provide a good user experience. So, if hiding and changing the referrer will provide a better user experience, why you think I am trying to do anything illegal.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. You can fake the referrer in your own browser, but you can't force someone else's browser to fake it.

What your solution will do is show the referrer as being your own website. That may still be better than it seemingly coming from nowhere. But, on the other hand, it may not. I'm no expert on the way that Youtube SEO works. I suspect, though, that anything which attempts to deliberately manipulate it is likely to hurt rather than help you. Let your content be its own best advert.

If you're determined to go down this route, though, an alternative solution would be to set up a Facebook page and embed the video in that. Then make the Facebook page the destination of the link in the PDF. That way, the referrer for the video really will be Facebook.

Comment: your solution for using a video embeded on a facebook page looks the perfect way to do this. The only downside is that this will decrease the view count. a visitor who come to youtube, I get a view by the auto-play. whereas, a visitor who go to an fb page, he may see that he received a message and decide to change his direction to chatting. Moreover, the user needs to click "play" to get a view counted. See.. on FB, there is a lot of distraction.

Answer (score 0):

Faking a URL isn't going to enhance your SEO. If you want to track traffic from that ebook, use UTM tagging in that embedded URL.

I'm not sure if this will be reflected in your YouTube stats, but should be easy to track in Google Analytics.