# How to get refering URL when redirected from some page to another page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am redirecting from several pages to dev.php using php header

```
<?php header(Location: dev.php); ?>
```

I want to know from where i have been redirected here.

I have tried

```
<?php
print "You entered using a link on ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
?>
```

but it dosent work as `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];` only works if you access dev.php using `<a href="dev.php">Go to Developer Page</a>`

So how can i get the referring URL?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like below.

```
<?php header(Location: dev.php?referrer=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]); ?>
```

## OR

```
header('Referer: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
header(Location: dev.php);
```

If above methods don't work, You will have to go with sessions.

Comment: `header('Referer: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` dosent work and I cant use dev.php to get variable

Comment: check the updated answer. it should work. set the header before use redirect.

Comment: yes i have used the updated one earlier first i set the `header('Referer: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` then redirected

Comment: If above methods don't work, You will have to go with sessions

Comment: The Referer header is a request-level header (see [RFC 1945 section 10.13](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945#section-10.13)) so setting it in a response has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the variable in GET:

```
<?php header('Location: dev.php?backurl='.$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]); ?>
```

And then take it in this way:

```
$backurl=$_GET['backurl'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `referer` to the header manually:

```
header("Referer: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // current page
header("Location: dev.php");
```

You can also do it using CURL. Have a look at an example function for that here:
[PHP - Referer redirect script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857427/php-referer-redirect-script)

Comment: I've added a link for a method using CURL.

Comment: The Referer header is a request-level header (see [RFC 1945 section 10.13](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945#section-10.13)) so setting it in a response has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] = 'YOUR_URL';
header('Location: dev.php');
exit(0);
```

Comment: this one dosent work in dev.php i am `echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF];` but its echoing/ printing nothing {blank}

Comment: In `dev.php`, you have to get the `HTTP_REFERER`, not `PHP_SELF`. So, do `echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`.

Comment: yes sorry i am echoing <?php
echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
?> i just mistaken in typing the comment

Answer (score 0):

The referer header is rather unreliable, there are antivirus software and firewalls out there that filter it completely. The only thing you can pretty safely rely on are cookies and with them, sessions.

Cookies are stored on the client side, in the browser, therefore can be manipulated, but if you are storing non-critical information, they can be enough.

Sessions nowadays rely on cookies as a means of starting them. A randomly generated hash is stored in a cookie, the corresponding data is stored on the server linked to this hash. When the client requests the next page, this data is retrieved. For more information about sessions read the [corresponding section of the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

As I wrote, sessions rely on cookies nowadays and you shouldn't do that unless you are aware of the security implications. You *can* however use URL parameters to pass the session ID along.

On a side note: in order to use cookies (and with them sessions) both the setting and the final URL must be on the same domain. If this isn't the case, you can use request parameters to pass the information along.