# Modifying Referer header before sending to next URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, header, referer

When server side PHP is executed , i want to empty or modify referer header using `.htaccess` or PHP code.

For example : `www.example.com/index.php?make=file`
In referer header its appearing like `www.example.com/index.php?make=file`

How i can make this header filed empty or modify to any characters before redirecting to other pages.

Comment: you can't, referer is browser set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857427/php-referer-redirect-script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857427/php-referer-redirect-script)